# Creating very large Tree View (More than 1M items) in GUI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, treeview

I am developing a GUI application, it has a TreeView (like the
left panel of Win32 Regedit) widget used to show lots of items,
which is the most important part of the application.

```
+----------------------------------+-+
|[root]                            |#|
|  +item                           |#|
|  -item                           |#|
|    +item                         | |
|    -item                         | |
|      item                        | |
|      item                        | |
|      ...                         | |
|    +item                         | |
|    +item                         | |
|    ...                           | |
|  +item                           | |
|  +item                           | |
|  ...                             | |
+----------------------------------+-+
```

Currently this application is build on Qt. My ListView is
inherited from QTreeView, and my ListModel is inherited from
QAbstractItemModel. They work together. After did some
optimizations to the code, the efficiency is much better than
before, but it's still lower than I excepted. According to my
test, the insert operation could be done in almost constant time,
so it's not a problem. The problem is drawing. While drawing, the
doItemsLayout method of QTreeView will be called if there are new
items. It will take more time if there are more items. At the
beginning, it's negligible. I can feel the latency on GUI if there
are more than 300K items while inserting. The doItemsLayout method
will take 80+ milliseconds if there are 1M items. The experience
on GUI is not good. Another problem is that QTreeView will run out
2GB user space on 32bit Windows (or Wow64) if there are more than
1M items, process just crashed. Maybe 2GB is not a very big
problem, because I could provide 64bit build.

After careful thought, I concluded the problem to be solved is
this: **To locate an item with its current row index**.

The vertical scrollbar of a TreeView gives us an index - the first
item's index. We must find and draw this item first, then simply
preorder walk the tree to get the rest of items. Only a few items
are needed at a given time, because the height of a TreeView is
limited. Sounds good, but it is not that simple.

There is only a root item at the beginning. New items will be
inserted frequently at runtime. And an item of TreeView could be
expanded or collapsed by the user if it has children(subitems). So
row indexes of items change often. The doItemsLayout of Qt is slow
because it insert all of the items to an vector container, and
uses the vector's subscript index as the item's row index. When
row indexes are going to be changed, this vector container
changes. So that will take O(n) time.

How to optimize this is my question. I am not talking about Qt, I
am talking about an usual GUI question. I can work on Qt or other
GUI libraries, that's not a problem. My goal is to support more
than 1M (more is better) of items in TreeView.

Is there any data structure or algorithm could help ? Any advice ?

---

**Edit**

If your advice is to divide items into parts, and only parts of
the tree is visible at once, **this thing is already done**. The
vertical scrollbar and the viewport is exactly what you are talking
about. In addition, I will provide filter, finder and other tools
to the user, the user do not need to handle all of the items at
once. So this is not a big problem.

Comment: Do not insert all items at once. If possible insert just the root item and its children, and upon node expansion add childs/grandchilds of expanded node.

Comment: How is the user going to handle 1M items? They can't all be visible at once, so perhaps you can populate just parts of the tree and expand/collapse  as the user moves around.

Comment: @BoPersson User do not need to handle all of the items. He will use filter, finder or other tools to locate items he care about. And only a few items in the viewport at a given time, so "parts" is already done.

Comment: @marom In extreme case, there are just root item and its children, but the number of children is huge. And yes, items are inserted in batches.

Comment: "He will use filter, finder or other tools to locate items he care about.” - then maybe just display the hits after he entered search criteria, instead of display 1M items initially?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld There are only a few hundred items initially. And items are collapsed by default. And viewport will do the clipping job. So I
never need to display 1M items. I must at least display the root,
so the user could browse this tree. Just like Win32 Regedit.

Comment: @amanjiang you should write your own `QAbstractItemModel` that supports data fetching.

Comment: SaZ is right. You must implement data fetching and add items to the model as they are requested by the view(s).

Comment: @SaZ I think data fetching is about lazy loading. When lots of children are loaded, doItemsLayout will take exactly the same time to insert them to the vector container. It will not solve the
problem. https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/gui/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#L3126

Comment: Other option: you may use sqlite as data storage and as backend for `QSqlTableModel `. Then you may do filtering with simple SQL queries. In most cases it will be much faster, then any custom filter implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem had been resolved last year.

The key of my solution is a data structure, I call it a "wide
array", I don't know if this data structure is used before.

A common array:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--
|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|...
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--
```

A "wide array":

```
+---+---------+-+---+-----+---+---+--
| a |    b    |c| d |  e  | f | g |...
+---+---------+-+---+-----+---+---+--
```

The idea is that every element in the "wide array" has a width
value, so that many indexes may map to one element, that is, many-
to-one mapping. The width of an element can be changed dynamically
in log(N) time, insert or locate an element will also take log(N)
time.

An element of a "wide array" is consider as a node of TreeView. A
node can be collapsed or expanded. When you collapse a node, its
width in the "wide array" is changed to 1. And when you expand a
node, its width in the "wide array" is changed to the sum of the
width of all its expanded child nodes. Based on this, locating a
visible item with a given row index is very fast.

The "wide array" is a variant of a 2-3 tree.